# how to create webhook for salesforce from external system ..?

Tags: apex

I need to create a webhook for salesforce in data insertion from external system(chargebee) for every event that occurs in chargebee that will hit the webhook URL to send notification in salesforce.
any idea how to start on it...

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should hit the [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) in your webhook, sending the data that you need to insert to a customObject or whatever you need to upsert.

In addition, if you need to run any logic or convert your external data, you could use a **trigger** `before/after insert` the object by REST API.

Take care with API [governor limits](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm).

Comment: Would you expand on your answer and explain why you prefer the REST API to using SOAP?

Comment: I think webhooks are by default a HTTP request... REST API seams to me the natural call receptor.

Comment: I have never worked on webhook before can you provide a snippet how to start in salesforce...any help will be highly appreciated...!!!